# Are there any examples of wlnets?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm looking for some examples of the new neural network file format ([.wlnet](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WLNet.html)) introduced in v11. Has anyone made or found any available ones, to import and use?

Comment: Yes I have read the docs

Comment: [`NetModel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetModel.html) has a few available.  There's at least one in the Wolfram Data Repository, but when I try to access it, it says permission denied.